# Link how many tickets for 1 Journey (timetable) ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model

Basically im trying to show how many tickets there is for one journey in the list view in the TimetableController not sure how to do it here is a basic Timetable Model

```
public class Timetable
{
    public int ID { get; set; }


    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime Schedual_Date { get; set; }

    public int EventID { get; set; }

    public int TrainID { get; set; }

    public DateTime Dep_Time { get; set; }

    public DateTime Arr_Time { get; set; }

    public string Dep_Location { get; set; }

    public string Arr_Location { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
    public virtual Train Train { get; set; }
    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }

}
```

And Here is a basic of Ticket Model

```
public int ID { get; set; }

    public Boolean Wheelchair { get; set; }

    public Boolean Carer { get; set; }

    public int FareID { get; set; }

    public int TimetableID { get; set; }

    public int BookingID { get; set; }

    public virtual Timetable Timetables { get; set; }

    public virtual Booking Bookings { get; set; }

    public virtual Fare Fares { get; set; }
```

Timetable Controller

```
 // GET: /Timetable/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var timetables = db.Timetables.Include(t => t.Event).Include(t => t.Train);
        return View(timetables.ToList());
    }
```

I need to return how many tickets have booked with timetable ID

View Controller

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayName("Timetable Ref")
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Schedual_Date)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Dep_Location)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Arr_Location)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Train.Name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Dep_Time)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Arr_Time)
    </th>

    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Schedual_Date)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dep_Location)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Arr_Location)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Train.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dep_Time)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Arr_Time)
    </td>

    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
    </td>
</tr>
```

}

thaks in advance would be allot help!!

Comment: `model.Tickets.Count()`?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code
                                                                                                                                                                  
Additional information: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Comment: Add a property for it and assign the value in the controller.

Comment: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tickets.Count())

Comment: What do you mean add a propety?

Comment: In your view model - `public int TicketCount { get; set; }` and set the value in the controller.

Comment: so I add that into my ticket model im not sure how to set the value as its dynamic...

Comment: It doesn't look like you're loading the related Tickets entities, var timetables = db.Timetables.Include(t => t.Event).Include(t => t.Train);

Comment: You really should be using a view model containing only the properties you want to display, then `List<TicketVM> model = timetables.Select(t => new TicketVM() { ID = t.ID, .....TicketCount = t.Tickets.Count() }); return View(model);`

Comment: @DavidMartin what do i need to include ?

Comment: var timetables = db.Timetables.Include(t => t.Event).Include(t => t.Train).Include(t => t.Tickets);